# R - Document-context matrix from dtm-tf and word embeddings

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-classification, word-embedding

I have a **term-frequency, document-term matrix** (dtm-tf) in which each row is a document, each column is a term, and each number in the matrix represents the number of occurences of the term in the document. I also have a **term-context matrix** (a matrix of word vectors/embeddings) where each row is a term from the dtm and each column is essentially number that can be used to relate it to other words used in a similar context.

Here is a very minimal reproducible example of what I have:

```
# Load packages
library(text2vec)

# Create documents
text <- c("I like cats.", "She like dogs.", "She dislikes cats.", "I dislike her.")

# Generate vectorizer
it <- itoken(text, preprocessor = tolower, tokenizer = word_tokenizer, progressbar = F)
vocab <- create_vocabulary(it)
vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab)

# Generate document-term matrix
dtm <- as.matrix(create_dtm(it, vectorizer))

# Generate word-context matrix
tcm <- create_tcm(it, vectorizer, skip_grams_window = 10)
glove <- GlobalVectors$new(word_vectors_size = 10, vocabulary = vocab, x_max = 10)
wv_main <- glove$fit_transform(tcm, n_iter = 10, convergence_tol = 0.01)
wv_context <- glove$components
word_vectors <- wv_main + t(wv_context)
```

From these, I would like to generate a **document-context matrix** where each row is a document and each column is a number indicative of context.

I think that the best way of going about this would be to average the corresponding values in the word vectors of every word in each document.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
dvm <- NULL
for (i in seq(nrow(dtm))) {
  terms <- names(which(dtm[i, ] != 0))
  dvm <- rbind(dvm, colMeans(word_vectors[terms, ]))
}
```

What would be the most efficient way for me to do this? If there are better methods than averaging, feel free to mention that as well.